# Error in POS printBitmap() method

Tags: android, thermal-printer

Im Using Citizen POSPrinter to print Digital Signature from my android application using bluetooth. But it prints only the byte[] array in the printer instead of printing the signature. I dono where im wrong. help me. Thanks in advance..

```
    ESCPOSPrinter posPtr = new ESCPOSPrinter();
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    String fname = "Sign.jpg";
    file = new File (root, fname);
    path = file.getAbsolutePath();

    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        signature.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        posPtr.printBitmap("//sdcard//Sign.jpg", CMPPrint.CMP_ALIGNMENT_RIGHT);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're saving the file with a `.jpg` extension, but using `Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG`. That seems unlikely to work. Also, you have catch blocks that don't actually handle the exception, but let the program continue in an erroneous state. If you get any I/O errors, your program will suffer mysterious, hard-to-debug errors later on - like the one you're trying to find.

I strongly suggest you work out how to handle exceptions properly before attempting to continue.

Comment: ya sure.. I ll learn how to handle it. But i get some special characters in the receipt. How to solve it..